# Is there a way to use parameters in a LOAD CSV command?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher script for populating a Neo4j (2.2.3) database. Currently, the names of all the CSV files are hard coded. Is there a way to parameterize the CSV files, in case I'd like to switch to a different web server or switch to using the local file system?

**Update**

I forgot to mention that my use case is via neo4j-shell. Is there also a way to define parameters for use by the shell or can that only be done through the REST API? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters in the shell, just export them as "environment" variables.
List them with `env`:

```
export name=Tim
env
match (p:Person {firstName:{name}}) return p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the URL for the CSV file is a string in the Cypher query so you can parameterize it like any other Cypher query. Check out the docs [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) and [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-parameters-java.html).